# Core Text availability

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-text

What platforms is Core Text available on from my understanding it is:

iPad 3.2 & iPhone 4.0+

Is this correct and it is not available in 3.2+ for iPhone?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no iOS 3.2+ for iPhone/iPod

The last 3.x version for iPhone/iPod is 3.1.3

SDK 3.2.x is for iPad.

4.x is only iPhone/iPod for now.

It seems that iPad will be getting the iOS 4, in November/2010 with the release iOS 4.2. (You can Google it).

Cheers

Comment: So only on iPhone 4 and iPad 3.2 and 4 (Soon) ? - That if so thats annoying.